# Declaring and using a variable in xml

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi i want to declare a variable and use it to set as an attribute in XML.

`<xsl:variable name="count" select="1"/>`

and i am using this variable like this

```
<param name="namelist" split=","  max-occurrences="&count;" max-len="1000"/>
```

can some one say proper way of doing this.
The purpose is i should have a value in count which will be used in many places in my xml file.
Since am new to XML suggest some sites where i could learn about XML variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >


<xsl:param name='count'>28</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xml>
    <xsl:element name='param>
        <xsl:attribute name='name'>namelist</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name='split'>,</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name='max-occurrences'><xsl:value-of select='$count'/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name='max-len'>100</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xml>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or you can construct the param element "in-line"...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
<xsl:param name='count'>28</xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xml>
    <param name='namelist' split=',' max-len='100'>
        <xsl:attribute name='max-occurrences'><xsl:value-of select='$count'/></xsl:attribute>
    </param>
</xml>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or this...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
<xsl:param name='count'>28</xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xml>
    <param name='namelist' split=',' max-len='100' max-occurrences='{$count}'/>
</xml>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: can't we set these attributes inline rather than doing like this?